# Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I create sp , I want get phonenumbers and split them , then insert into database

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Mysp_ExistphoneInsert]
@Numbers nvarchar(MAX),
@countryID int
as
insert into tblPhoneNumber (PhoneNumber , [Enabled] , CountryID)
Values ((select Item from dbo.MyFunc_Split(@Numbers, ',')) , 1 , @countryID)
```

its a sample of my data pas to @Numbers :
"201001000009,201001000006,201001000005,201001000004,201001000002,201001000000,"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select` rather than `insert . . . values`:

```
insert intotblPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber, [Enabled], CountryID)
    select Item, 1, @countryID
    from dbo.MyFunc_Split(@Numbers, ',');
```